# Running Redirect Test – Does client-side URL change?

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing, google-optimize

When doing a redirect test with Google Optimize, does the user see the url variants in their url bar?

For example if I'm comparing homepage.com with homepage_2.com, are certain users going to see homepage2.com in their browser, or will both variants be displayed on homepage.com?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the browser actually gets redirected to your variant URLs, once the user is eligible to participate in your test, and was included in one of the test variants. This means, that these users will see the URL of the tested page in their browser tabs.

There is a dedicated [support page](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/6361119) about requirements and considerations of a redirect test.